# Syntax error in javascript in CDATA section

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I get a javascript syntax error in an XHTML document, in a CDATA within a script element. (Safari 5.1)

```
for (var j = 0; j &lt; observers.length; j++) {
```

SyntaxError: Expected token ')'

Isn't this supposed to be legal?

Comment: `&lt;` is wrong, it should be `<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

In a CDATA, no XML escapes are processed.
You should just write `<`.